# Safely wiring AA batteries for consumer Arduino product

Tags: power, batteries, basic

How do I safely wire AA batteries to improve an Arduino-like device lifetime?
Discussion here in the Forum [[1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/how-do-i-connect-two-identical-batteries-to-increase-the-consumer-lifetime)] and the Battery University [[2](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/serial_and_parallel_battery_configurations)] suggests that using parallel AA batteries could be dangerous for consumer products due to someone inadvertently using cells that are not well matched. Moreover, it is not clear from the forum discussion (see @Matt. B comments) if series AA batteries do or do not improve an Arduino-like device lifetime. Hence, my questions are:

- Is there a way to safely wire parallel batteries thus avoiding misuses?
- Does series AA batteries also improve device lifetime even though this configuration does not increase the overall capacity?

Thanks.

Comment: My Microsoft mouse has two AA parallel batteries.

Comment: Well, I am very inexperienced in the subject and I am only concerned with the comments from the other post in the forum [1].  There, a user said that: "No product that takes AA alkalines wires them in parallel". Hence my concern and doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR;** There are lots of ways you can make a design far more energy efficient before even bothering worrying about what battery configuration to use.

---

> Is there a way to safely wire parallel batteries thus avoiding misuses

I've seen more than one consumer product with alkaline batteries simply connected in parallel. In fact the very mouse I am using at this moment is wired in that configuration. (Interestingly, I can unplug one battery and it still works fine).

There is a reason why many consumer devices advise against mixing new/old batteries or different chemistries. If you have one old and one new, they are going to be less efficient regardless of whether in parallel or series. Either configuration, one is not pulling its weight to coin a phrase.

You could start adding series diodes to prevent one battery charging another, but for a single AA cell, you would be wasting up to 30% of the energy of the battery in the diodes.

If we were talking Li-Ion or Li-Po, or higher voltage chains of batteries, I would advise using additional protection (if only because Li batteries have this nasty habit of explosive violence if mistreated). However for a pair of AA alkaline batteries, it's simply not worth it.

> Does series AA batteries also improve device lifetime

It depends. Theoretically, if you were to connect an ideal DC-DC convert to the batteries to step it down from the total series voltage, to a single battery voltage, then yes, series is better. This is because batteries will provide a higher total capacity when the current draw is lower (think internal resistance).

However, in practice a DC-DC is not ideal. It might be 95% efficient, or maybe 80% efficient (again, it depends). In which case the benefit of running the batteries at lower current draw might be wiped out by the DC-DC inefficiency.

> even though this configuration does not increase the overall capacity?

This is incorrect. Placing batteries in series *does* in fact increase the overall energy capacity.

But wait I hear you ask. If each cell has a rated capacity of "X" Ah, then placed in parallel you have "2X" Ah but in series you still have "X" Ah. What gives? Voltage is doubled, that's what.

The Ah rating of a battery doesn't increase by placing more cells in series, however the energy capacity does. Energy is measured in Joules or Watt-Hours (Wh) if you prefer. One Joule is one Amp times one Volt. If you double the voltage while keeping Ah the same, you double the Wh.

---

> to improve an Arduino-like device lifetime

The first thing I would suggest, is ensure that your circuit is designed as carefully as possible, keeping energy usage in mind.

- Are you using linear regulators? They turn voltage into heat, wasting precious energy
- Are you running the MCU at 5V when you could run it at 3.3V? It will burn more power
- Are any LEDs high efficiency ones? You can get 1mA LEDs quite readily, which will consume far less power than standard 20mA LEDs.

Then ask yourself, are you being efficient in software?

- If you find your MCU is spending large amounts of time in busy loops doing nothing, then start looking at putting it to sleep. An ATMega in deep sleep will use ~1uA sleeping vs 20mA in a `while(1)` loop.
- Can you reduce the processor frequency? If your software is simple, you may get away with running it at a much lower frequency. Why burn dynamic power clocking at 16MHz, when 1MHz (or even less) would suffice.
- Have you shut down any unnecessary peripherals? ATMegas have power reduction registers.

Comment: Thorough answer and great tips, @Tom. Could you clear a few remaining doubts, please? **1.** Un-even parallel AA batteries may not damage each other (as mentioned in [1] Matt B. answer)? I am worried about any "risks" of using this configuration. **2.** As far as I understood, if I were to reduce 4 series AA batteries supplied voltage of 6V to 3V, my extra capacity benefits could be wiped out by the DC-DC converter efficiency. Therefore, 2s2p AA batteries would effectively provide more "energy capacity", right? It seems obvious the answer, but I think it is wise to ask :)

Comment: @delirium **1.** you aren't going to damage the batteries putting them in parallel, just shorten their working life if heavily mismatched.

Comment: @delirium **2.** 4S1P with a DC-DC could be better than 2S2P but it depends on your current draw. Series with DC-DC would be highly beneficial at larger current draws (100+mA). However for very low current draw (e.g. <10mA) the losses from the DC-DC would probably dominate. The big advantage of having a DC-DC though is that as the battery voltage varies during discharge, the DC-DC gives you a nice stable output voltage.

Comment: Interesting. Lastly, could you point to any reference for further studying this topic? It seems rather "tricky" to choose the optimum AA battery setup for a beginner and I would like to further delve into the subject. Thanks for sharing your time and knowledge. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

> How do I safely wire AA batteries

Wire them in parallel and ignore the idiots on the forum.

I'm sure you read about the topic on Battery University Learn section, risk is minimal.  There is some good information on Li-ion safety.

AA Alkaline are very safe, as well as NiMH AA. There are no Li-ion AA.

The best battery for a device is a battry where the cuttoff discharge voltage is close to the device voltage.
For 3.3v device a Li-ion 
For a 5v device two Li-ion in series